# How to Put an Image on HTML and Make it Go Across Page?

Tags: html, image, resize

Some computers have smaller displays, so, how do I put an image that will resize to go across the whole page? This is for a banner.
Also, if it does resize, won't the quality change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

easiest answer: `<img width="100%" src="path/img/img.jpg">`

This will make the image fill the container that it is located in. If that container, a `<div>` for example, is smaller than the width of your screen then the image will not fill the width of your whole screen as it will only fill the width of the container element.